How to Continuously Merge PDFs Without Adding Extra Pages Using iText 5
I'm working on merging multiple PDFs using iText 5 in Java. My goal is to merge the PDFs in such a way that the second PDF starts immediately after the content of the first PDF ends, if there is space left on the last page of the first PDF. However, when I merge the pdf, the second pdf starts from another page even if there is a lot of space left in the first pdf file.
Here is my simple code
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class MergePDFs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream("Merged.pdf"));
            document.open();

            PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader("First.pdf");
            PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader("Second.pdf");

            int n1 = reader1.getNumberOfPages();
            for (int i = 1; i <= n1; i++) {
                PdfImportedPage page = copy.getImportedPage(reader1, i);
                copy.addPage(page);
            }

            int n2 = reader2.getNumberOfPages();
            for (int i = 1; i <= n2; i++) {
                PdfImportedPage page = copy.getImportedPage(reader2, i);
                copy.addPage(page);
            }

            document.close();
            reader1.close();
            reader2.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


Pdf is not a document editing format.
The PDF document page based. When you want to add content to the end of an existing page, you possibly have to split the page you add, requiring reflowing its content. Or arbitrarily cut it so you could cut a text line or image in parts.

The reason is because you simply getting a page from a PDF file and copying it right to the copy object without checking if the page is blank or something. To check that, have a look at a sample I found on another question on SO: enter link description here it runs on a different library than iText. You could iterate from the end to start and count how many ending pages in a row are possible blanks.
Another thing is you have some code duplications (doubled for loop) and you should consider enclosing document, reader1, reader2 in try-with-resources.
Good luck!

This question isn't about blank pages.
